# Building a full adder, trouble with 7406 inverter

Tags: inverter, buffer

I understand the logic of a full adder, but having trouble with TTL. I think I understand why my test circuit give me the inverse output with my little LED: by closing the A input circuit to the TTL XOR, A is shorted to ground, lowering the voltage triggering the TTL output to +5v making the voltage drop across the LED to near 0 thus, it turns of --a sign that the XOR is giving me the "true" value.

I wanted to use an inverter 7406 TTL to get the LED to shine to match the "true" state of the output of the XOR 
TTL but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

In brief, what do I not undertsand about the wiring of an inverter (a NOT gate) that is keeping me from doing this right?

Any help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGmqH.jpg)

[image]

Comment: please provide a circuit diagram

Comment: What @JonRB says. Many beginners start to complain here and say things like "but the breadboard is clear". I'm sure you  won't say "the breadboard is clear", because, well, it isn't (which isn't bad), and we really can't answer your question well if we have to wildly guess what is connected to what on a breadboard.

Comment: Tbf... That looks like the spaghetti bolognese i had for supper.  I have never used a breadboard and have either used veraboard or PCB... Each still had a circuit

Comment: I appreciate that this is a jumble of pasta. I take exception to the bolognese comment, I feel like it is more like alfredo. However, in the future I will use the website WhatRoughBeast used to show my work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included a schematic, but your problem seems pretty clear. Actually, both of them. Well, now that I look closely, three of them.

1) This is easy. You need to connect pin 7 of your 7406 to ground. Why your LED is operating at all is a mystery. Apparently the floating ground of the 7406 allows current paths within the 7406 to conduct in the reverse of normal operation, and the IC is acting as a current limiting resistor. Your picture shows both inputs to the XOR grounded, so the output is low. If the 7406 were were operating, its output would be high (since it's an inverter) and the LED would be off. But before you run off and fix this, you need to read the rest of the answer.

2) This will take some explaining. First, you need to be aware that TTL has two kinds of outputs: totem-pole and open collector. The 7486 you use has totem pole outputs. The output can provide a current out when high ("source current"), and accept current in when low ("sink current"). For TTL, totem pole outputs are much better at sinking current than they are at sourcing. I'll get back to this.

Open collector outputs, such as a 7406, behave like a switch to ground. They cannot source current. Just like your switches, a TTL gate input connected to an open collector output needs a pullup resistor to function reliably. Note "reliably". Just to confuse you, a floating TTL input will actually pull up to have a high input. The reason you need a pullup is because the input will not be strongly pulled up, and will occasionally start misbehaving, particularly if there is strong RF in the area. You should get in the habit of providing pullups on unused inputs, since once you switch over to CMOS this becomes important.

3) Finally, as I mentioned earlier, TTL does not do well sourcing current, so any sort of external load is usually best served by connecting one end to +5 and pulling the other end low, as you have done with your LED. But - TTL isn't a really strong current sink (rated for 16 mA), and trying to drive an LED directly will be too much for it. You need a current limiting resistor (470 to 1k is a good starting point).

So, here's the final configuration you should be using

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKksNl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order:

1) Ground your 7406 pin 7.

2) Put a 1k resistor in series with your LED.

3) If you decide to go with 2 7406s in series, provide a 1k pullup resistor to +5 on the input of the second.

Comment: Thank so very much for your answer. I understand much better now.